# What is the difference between 7TeV and 13.6 TeV ? Why don't we just dump the low energy data and use the one with highest energy?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, data-analysis, large-hadron-collider

I saw some results from particle physics that combines 7 TeV and 13.6 TeV results but they are different. Why they are different? Why do we combine them? If we need them why did LHC stopped taking more data with lower energy?

Comment: Which reference? Which page?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

There is too much variety among LHC measurements to give a concrete answer: the arguments of which dataset to use can vary on a case-by-case basis.

Generally the precision of particle physics measurements depends strongly on the sample size (typically by the time you are "systematics-limited" the measurement is low-hanging fruit that has already been picked, but not always) so usually it is worth including as much data as you have collected.

Indeed the 13 TeV data has higher interaction cross-sections and more integrated luminosity than 7 or 8 TeV, and now we are collecting 13.6 TeV data that will be the case for that soon enough. I have known some cases in LHCb where we dropped the 7 TeV data (particularly for $\Lambda_b$ decays) because the additional work estimating systematic uncertainties would have been more effort than it was worth (you also have to make practical considerations like "will this analysis be done in time for this PhD thesis to be written?").

Then there are some corner cases where it doesn't make sense to combine the datasets at different energies.
If you are doing a measurement whose precision is super sensitive to the multiplicity of particles in the collision, the lower energy data may be easier to work with. If you are doing an energy-dependent measurement (e.g. a cross-section) then you'd have to analyse the data at each energy separately.